# how to get values from the array with the help of for loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop

In my ios app,
i have some data in one array,now i want to print that data with the help of NSlog in viewdidload , but i want to show that data inside one for loop...so i didn't get what should be my for loop.

i want to get values from the array with the help of using for...loop... how can i do that ?

```
storedDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Kaushal"];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Bhaumik"];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Arpit"];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Swapnil"];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Megha"];

[storedDataArray addObject:@"Ravi"];

for (int i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    NSLog(@"hello %d",storedDataArray);
}
```

Comment: use  `storedDataArray[i]` and replace static 6 with  `storedDataArray.count`

Answer (score 1):

is not

```
for (int i=0; i<=6; i++) {
NSLog(@"hello %d",storedDataArray);
}
```

it is

```
for (int i=0; i<storedDataArray.count; i++) {
NSLog(@"hello %@",storedDataArray[i]);
}
```

**fast enumration**

```
for (NSString *name in storedDataArray) {
NSLog(@"hello %@",name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add index in storedDataArray**

```
for (int i=0; i<storedDataArray.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"hello %@",storedDataArray[i]);
}
```

**Or you can do without index**

```
for (NSString *str in storedDataArray) {
    NSLog(@"hello %@",str);
}
```